# Pointer pointed to string passed by function in C++

Tags: c++, string, function, pointers

I have a question on the pointer used by string in a function. my code is below.

```
void printName(int *max,int *min,string *maxFirst, string *maxLast)
{
        ifstream infile;
        infile.open("input.txt");
        string firstName,lastName;
        float age;
        infile>>firstName>>lastName;
        while(firstName!="Term") {
        infile>>age;

    if(age==*max)
       {
         maxFirst=&firstName;
         maxLast=&lastName;
         cout<<*maxFirst<<' '<<*maxLast<<endl;
       }
    }
```

To use this function, in main(), I define it like

```
int main()
{
 void printName(int *,int *,string *,string *);
 int *pMaxAge, *pMinAge;
 string *maxFirst,*maxLast;
 pMaxAge=&maxAge;
 pMinAge=&minAge;

 printName(pMaxAge,pMinAge,maxFirst,maxLast);
 cout<<"\nThe oldest employee is "<<*maxFirst<<' '<<
         *maxLast<<endl;
}
```

I skip some part of my code. While the first cout works fine, the second one doesn't work. Is there any problem with my pointer passing please?

Thanks.

Comment: Important parts of your code seem to be missing (specifically, the definions of maxAge, minAge, firstName and lastName)

Comment: `maxFirst` and `maxLast` should probably be pointers to pointers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have them in my code but I skip them when I paste it. The program read firstName and lastName from another file.

Comment: Hello obvlious, thanks. Why maxFirst and maxLast should be those please?

Comment: Please do not skip them, their declaration is of great importance, especially the scope they are declared at.

Comment: Hi, I add the part that I define firstName and lastName, thanks.

Comment: @CaptainOblivious surely a reference is better than a pointer to pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding of pointers is a complete mess. You should go and RTFM on pointers, from the ground up. Nothing you do here makes sense.

First you declare 4 pointers, not initialized to anything. Then you pass them to a function which takes pointer arguments **by value**, and expect changing the pointers' values to affect anything outside the function.

You should allocate these variables in your main function, and then pass them either by reference or by address, and assign to them properly when doing so.

For instance:

```
void printName(int *max,int *min,string *maxFirst, string *maxLast)
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("input.txt");
    string firstName,lastName;
    float age;
    infile>>firstName;
    while(firstName!="Term") {
        infile>>lastName>>age;

        if(age==*max)
        {
            *max = (int)age;
            *maxFirst=firstName;
            *maxLast=lastName;
            cout<<*maxFirst<<' '<<*maxLast<<endl;
        }
        infile>>firstName;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int MaxAge = 0, MinAge;
    string maxFirst,maxLast;

    printName(&MaxAge,&MinAge,&maxFirst,&maxLast);
    cout<<"\nThe oldest employee is "<<maxFirst<<' '<<
         maxLast<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the printName function you need to assign to the content of the pointer:

```
*maxFirst = firstName;
*maxLast = lastName;
```

You also need to pass pointers to the existing variables as function arguments:

```
string maxFirst;
string maxLast;
printName(pMaxAge, pMinAge, &maxFirst, &maxLast);
```

The same probably applies to the integer arguments.

Comment: Thank for the hint. In my code, is my definition like            maxFirst=&firstName;
maxLast=&lastName;    incorrect please?

Comment: @user3684119 I still can't spot from your sample, how `firstName` / `lastName` are declared/defined. Provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question please!

Comment: Hi, I add the part that I define firstName and lastName, thanks.